# Exception Exception: s4s-elt-invalid-content. Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often

Tags: java, xml, xsd, saxparser, xsd-validation

Currently i am using Altova IDE for desgning XSD now in Altove XSD looks ok and validate the XMl, but whenever i am trying to Validating XML against same XSD in Java code it will give me Exception,

I am using XSD 1.1 version.

I have used All and assert tag in XSD.

**My Java code is:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLValidation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



      System.out.println("SampleXML_1 validates against final_schema.xsd? Status is :"+validateXMLSchema("src/final_schema.xsd", "src/SampleXML_1.xml"));


      }

    public static boolean validateXMLSchema(String xsdPath, String xmlPath){

        try {
            SchemaFactory factory = 
                    SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));
        } catch (IOException | SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have tries this also:

```
            factory.setProperty("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/xsd-version", "1.1");
```

**My XSD Code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="modes">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="A" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:attributeGroup name="enabled-attributes">
        <xs:attribute name="attr1" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="attr2" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:attributeGroup>
    <xs:attributeGroup name="disabled-attributes">
        <xs:attribute name="attr3" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="attr4" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:attributeGroup>
    <xs:element name="A">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="B" type="xs:int"/>
                <xs:element name="C" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:all>
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="disabled-attributes"/>
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="enabled-attributes"/>
            <xs:attribute name="mode" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                        <xs:enumeration value="ENABLE"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="DISABLE"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:assert test="(@mode='ENABLE'  and @attr1 and @attr2 and not(@attr3) and not(@attr4)) 
                          or (@mode='DISABLE' and @attr3 and @attr4 and not(@attr1) and not(@attr2))"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: From the error message you quote, the problem appears to be in your XSD schema; providing Java code is unlikely to throw any light on the error.

Comment: Be sure your XSD includes the `minVersion` attribute from the *XML Schema versioning* namespace: `xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1"`

Comment: Hello Sir, can you please check it again i have add XSD file also. Thanks

Comment: I have included but still not working,i have also update my question can you check it again, i was also trying online tool for validating Schema still it fails.